# how to apply set and ignorecase in a single datacolumn in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a df,

```
 Keys        
 one, ONE    
 ram, Ram
 kumar
 Raj,rAj
 cricket
 level,LeVel
 kum,num
```

first I want to apply set and ignore case on df["Keys"], make it a single value and achieve

```
 df
Name
one
ram
kumar
raj
cricket
level
kum,num
```

2nd operation,

I have a list and my above DataFrame, df["name"]

```
 my_list=["ONE","Ram","CRICKEt","KUm"]
```

I need compare `df["name"].str.lower.split(,) with my_list.lower()`

if a value present in my_list then we need to change in df["Name"]

My desired output is,

```
 df,
 name
 ONE
 Ram
 kumar
 raj
 CRICKEt
 level
 KUm,num
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) + [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) + `apply` + [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['Name'] = df['Keys'].str.lower().str.split(',').apply(set).str.join(',')
print (df)
          Keys     Name
0      one,ONE      one
1      ram,Ram      ram
2        kumar    kumar
3      Raj,rAj      raj
4      cricket  cricket
5  level,LeVel    level
6      kum,num  num,kum
```

If is possible after `,` are whitespaces use `,\s*` for separator - comma +  zero or more:

```
df['Name'] = df['Keys'].str.lower().str.split(',\s*').apply(set).str.join(',')
print (df)
          Keys     Name
0     one, ONE      one
1     ram, Ram      ram
2        kumar    kumar
3      Raj,rAj      raj
4      cricket  cricket
5  level,LeVel    level
6      kum,num  num,kum
```

EDIT:

Last create dictionary and then replace:

```
my_list=["ONE","Ram","CRICKEt","KUm"]
d = dict(zip([x.lower() for x in my_list],my_list))
print (d)
{'cricket': 'CRICKEt', 'one': 'ONE', 'ram': 'Ram', 'kum': 'KUm'}

splitted = df['Keys'].str.lower().str.split(',').apply(set)
df['Name'] = splitted.str.join(',').replace(d, regex=True)
df['Count'] = splitted.str.len()
print (df)
          Keys     Name  Count
0      one,ONE      ONE      1
1      ram,Ram      Ram      1
2        kumar    KUmar      1
3      Raj,rAj      raj      1
4      cricket  CRICKEt      1
5  level,LeVel    level      1
6      kum,num  num,KUm      2
```

Comment: good, now I want to do one more operation, I will edit the question

Comment: no ,the first solution is not working, its converting to lower case but still `df["keys"]=one, one`

Comment: I tried both your solution but still I am having `df["keys"]=one,one`

Comment: no, we dont need tocare about spaces, we care about comma(,)

Comment: The first solution is works fine, @jezrael . Now we have one more thing to do ill update the question ok ?

Comment: we are supposed to have `ONE` not `ONE,ONE`

Comment: your code works fine, but you posted wrong output. Thanks for the solution

Comment: now how to calculate the length of df[name].split(",")

I did, `df["count"]=len(df["pre-keys"].str.split(","))` but getting 4 as length

Comment: I know this method, is there any other way to find the length as per your previous solution with only using df["Name"]

Comment: Yes, but it is a little hack `df['Count'] = df['Name'].str.count(',') + 1`

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. I will apply it on my main data and see

Comment: Hi @jezrael, can you look into this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47131193/value-matching-between-two-dataframes-using-pandas-in-python