# matching values between two dataframes with a condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have two dataframes,

df1,

```
    Values
 0  Sri
 1  pyd
 2  NaN
 3  sri, is
 4  keyboard
 5  kumar,cricketer
```

df2,

```
 Values         | Names
 Sri            | Sri is a good player
 NaN            | NaN   
 sri, is        | Sri is a good player
kumar,cricketer | Kumar is a cricketer
```

I am trying to update the df1 by comparing df1 and df2. df1["Values"] will have df2["Values"] and more. if a value present in df1 and df2 then I want to map the corresponding df2["Names"] in df1["Names"]

my desired output is

df1,

```
    Values            |    Names
 0  Sri               |  Sri is a good player
 1  pyd               |  NaN   
 2  NaN               |  NaN   
 3  sri, is           |  Sri is a good player
 4  keyboard          |  NaN
 5  kumar,cricketer   |  Kumar is a cricketer
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47305897/matching-rows-between-dataframes-in-pandas-in-python?noredirect=1#comment81724970_47305897

Comment: no, this is not duplicate, there they are creating a new dataframe not on existing one, please check

Comment: But the solution in either case would be the same, correct?

Comment: try `pd.merge(df, df2, how='left', on='Values')`.

Comment: no, see the df1 and df2 both are different but in my case i have same values in df1 and df2, they are doing more operation. In my case  I need to map the values between two df's if the same keyword in another df

Comment: @umutto , I am getting `NaN` on the first row `Sri`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ , did you check

Comment: This will be an ordinary set index and mapping. There are many answers for this question.

Comment: @pyd Are the Values columns same type on both dataframes? Merge on left works for me.

Comment: yes, it is of same type